# Can I create multiple DB instances in one AWS DB cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to create multiple database instances in one cluster. for an example like All my DEV application DB should be in one cluster.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by placing multiple *database instances* in a single cluster?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an AWS DB cluster, you can create it using Amazon Aurora DB cluster.

According to [Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.html) : 
An Amazon Aurora DB cluster consists of one or more DB instances and a cluster volume that manages the data for those DB instances. An Aurora cluster volume is a virtual database storage volume that spans multiple Availability Zones, with each Availability Zone having a copy of the DB cluster data. Refer the link for more details.

Follow this link to [create Amazon Aurora DB Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.CreateInstance.html)

Secondly, if you are using Cloud Formation for your deployment, you can use **"AWS::RDS::DBCluster"** resource in your template.
It also creates a cluster, such as an Aurora for Amazon RDS (Amazon Aurora) DB cluster.

Below is the JSON Syntax for the RDS DBCluster resource :

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
  "Properties" :
  {
    "AvailabilityZones" : [ String, ... ],
    "BacktrackWindow" : Integer,
    "BackupRetentionPeriod" : Integer,
    "DatabaseName" : String,   
    "DBClusterIdentifier" : String,
    "DBClusterParameterGroupName" : String,
    "DBSubnetGroupName" : String,
    "DeletionProtection" : Boolean,
    "EnableCloudwatchLogsExports" : [ String, ... ],
    "EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication" : Boolean,
    "Engine" : String,
    "EngineMode" : String,
    "EngineVersion" : String,
    "KmsKeyId" : String,
    "MasterUsername" : String,
    "MasterUserPassword" : String,
    "Port" : Integer,
    "PreferredBackupWindow" : String,
    "PreferredMaintenanceWindow" : String,
    "ReplicationSourceIdentifier" : String,
    "ScalingConfiguration" : ScalingConfiguration,
    "SourceRegion" : String,
    "SnapshotIdentifier" : String,
    "StorageEncrypted" : Boolean,
    "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
    "VpcSecurityGroupIds" : [ String, ... ]
  }
}
```

Refer this [link for creating an Amazon RDS DB Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html)

This should help.